# AWS Cognito IntitiateAuth: Missing required parameter UserName

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, single-responsibility-principle

When initializing an authentication to AWS Cognito, the API is rejecting my request:

```
InvalidParameterException: Missing required parameter UserName
status code: 400,
```

Here is the content of the request (yes, I tried putting it everywhere, no success).

```
params := &cognitoidentityprovider.InitiateAuthInput{
    AuthFlow: aws.String("USER_SRP_AUTH"),              // Required
    ClientId: aws.String("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"), // Required
    AuthParameters: map[string]*string{
        "username":     aws.String("myUser"), // Required
        "UserName":     aws.String("myUser"), // Required
    },
    ClientMetadata: map[string]*string{
        "username":     aws.String("myUser"), // Required
        "UserName":     aws.String("myUser"), // Required
    },
}
```

Any idea about what would be the problem please?
Considering to the doc (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-dg-pdf.pdf), `username` should be in AuthParameters along with `srpA`. Would it be possible that the problem comes from srpA? If so, what is this? It looks like that it is the password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be in AuthParameters, not ClientMetadata.

I believe the expected values are USERNAME and SRP_A.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are correct!
However for SRP_A, I assume it refers to the password.
When I put the initial password, I am receiving:
`InvalidParameterException: 1 validation error detected: Value 'toto123456' at 'a' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^[0-9a-fA-F]+$` 
And when I put some string matching the expression, I, of course, get:
`InvalidParameterException: Invalid input given` 
What is exactly SRP_A value please? The doc doesn't mention it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

SRP_A is a large integer as defined by the Secure Remote Password Protocol. Are you trying to do SRP or just authenticate with username and password. For username/password authentication you should use the AdminInitiateAuth operation.

Comment: Admin operations are for secured backend server to avoid SRP calculation apparantly. Do you think it is a good idea to use that on the client side (mobile app)?
If not, does that mean I have to implement the all SRP calculation on the client side? 
I am hoping that Cognito API is using a certificate, so that I can just send the password in plain text, though TLS.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to use AdminInitiateAuth from a mobile app. In that case, yes you would need to implement SRP from your mobile app. Currently, we provide SDKs for Android, iOS, and Javascript that do the SRP calculations. An example of a Javascript implementation can be found in our SDK: https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/